# What's the difference between PipelinedRDD and normal RDD in Apache Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

now i tried to load the data from the hdfs with the code below, and I tried to use the function 'jsonParse' to concatenate values to normal csv, so that i think i can get the normal string RDD as i need, but it seems that this method is not work, and them when i tried to print some of the records, it tells me that the 'data' variable is a PipelinedRDD not iterate-able, any one can tell how can i get the 'data'(normal rdd) want, thanks:

```
def jsonParse(x):
    s=json.loads(x)
    print "ssssssssssss"+s['age']+","+s['sex']+","+s['xueya']+","+s['danguchun']+","+s['na']+","+s['k']+","+s['yaowu']
    return s['age']+","+s['sex']+","+s['xueya']+","+s['danguchun']+","+s['na']+","+s['k']+","+s['yaowu']

conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
hc = HiveContext(sc)
#json=sc.textFile('hdfs://hacluster/new')
json=hc.sql("select * from default.test_yj_200 limit 1000").toJSON()

data=json.map(jsonParse)
```

Answer (score 2):

**PipelinedRDD**

PipelinedRDD operations are pipelined and sent to worker; the code is executed from top to bottom. It is a subclass of RDD.

**RDD**

Represents a constant, partitioned collection of elements that can be worked on in parallel.